# Create a custom cell for iOS app using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First of all, I'm going insane trying to create a custom cell in iOS. Following dozens of other question answers, I don't seem to be getting the same result and I can't find out why. My use case: create a custom cell used in a table view, simple.

I have a table view sitting inside a UIView, with a single cell with a single label:
[image]

I gave my cell an identifier:

[image]

I link a custom class to the cell in the storyboard:

[image]

I link the label in the cell to an outlet on my custom class:
[image]

Here is the code from my view controller:

```
    class LoggedInViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        @IBOutlet weak var tmImage: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var tmNameLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var tmMeetingLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var attendeesTableView: UITableView!

        //Test table view details
        let names: [String] = ["Bobby", "Mark", "Waldo"]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

            //Setup table and cells
            attendeesTableView.delegate = self
            attendeesTableView.dataSource = self
            self.attendeesTableView.register(LoggedInTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "attendeeCell")
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.names.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell: LoggedInTableViewCell = self.attendeesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "attendeeCell", for: indexPath) as! LoggedInTableViewCell
            cell.cellNameLabel?.text = self.names[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

And when this is ran, it returns nothing and the cell being returned from the method above is nil when printing:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please fix the posted code. As posted now, it looks like the two table view data source methods are inside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Why are you registering a cell when you have already done so via then Storyboard? Also, how many Sections are you returning?

Comment: Inexperience following tutorials, it looks like the register was conflicting and causing the issue. I'm able to get what I need successfully now, thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to call the `register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` instance method on your `attendeesTableView`. Removing this line should fix the cells not displaying.

The reason for this is you created the cell in the storyboard itself. Alternatively, if you designed it in a nib you would need to register it.

Matt Neuberg has an excellent and detailed explanation on designing a custom cell using the storyboard in his book titled "Programming iOS 10, Seventh Edition".

Here is a quote from his book regarding why you should not register if you are using the storyboard:

> In your table view controller code, make sure you do not call
>   register(_:for- CellReuseIdentifier:). If you do call it, you will be
>   telling the runtime not to get the cell from the storyboard. (Neuberg, 2016, p. 469)

Neuberg, M. (2016). Programming iOS 10 7th Edition. California: O’Reilly Media

Comment: While it is better to reference the parameter, this change will have absolutely no effect in this case since the only table view here is `self.attendeesTableView`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. You are correct. My original answer does not address the core issue. I have revised my answer.